# Double linking Rust structs

Tags: rust, linked-list, ownership

I am trying to implement a collection of objects where each of its contained objects also has a non-mutable reference to the collection to which they belong.

However, I am having trouble finding a safe way to do so. Basically, each time I try to instantiate one element of that collection, the mutability or ownership of the collection's reference changes, and then it is impossible to complete the missing steps.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to do, you will notice the compiler is complaining.

```rust
struct Collection<'a> {
    elements: Vec<Element<'a>>,
}

struct Element<'a> {
    collection: &'a Collection<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Element<'a> {
    fn new(collection: &'a mut Collection<'a>) -> &'a mut Self {
        let element = Self { collection }; // immutable borrow occurs here
        collection.elements.push(element); // cannot borrow `collection.elements` as mutable
        collection.elements.last_mut().unwrap() // cannot borrow `collection.elements` as mutable
    }
}
```

[See this in the Rust playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3a8b7732e0102f7d5fbe969da5ff004)

Looking at the linked list implementation, I have seen they are using raw pointers. But IMHO the point would be avoiding unsafe blocks, since I will need to dereference them.

**So my question is**: Is there any safe way to achieve what I am trying to do? Is this a very bad idea? Or should I use raw pointers, like in the linked list implementation?

Comment: I think the duplicate I linked answers your question. If it doesn't, please let me know here in the comments.

Comment: Also related: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: You are right SvenMarnach .  Thank you a lot! Should I remove this question then?

Comment: No, please keep it here. Search engines will index your question and make it easier for other people to find the answer. I'll link more relevant questions here soon.